# Sencha Unable to locate supported Framework

Tags: sencha-touch

I am new in sencha and this my first App. I tried to create an App in sencha touch through following command

sencha -sdk /home/tanmay/amit_mob/adt-bundle-linux-x86-20140702/sdk generate app MyApp /home/tanmay/amit_mob/myapp

But I get an error

```
[ERR] Unable to locate supported Framework.

  Please ensure this command was executed from a supported framework
  directory or that a framework directory was specified via the -sdk      switch.
   For example:

  sencha -sdk /path/to/framework-dir generate app AppName path/to/app

[ERR] com.sencha.exceptions.ExState: Not a framework directory : /home/tanmay/amit_mob/sdk/tools
 at com.sencha.cli.AbstractCommand$Property.set(AbstractCommand.java:406)
 at com.sencha.cli.AbstractCommand.processConfigParam(AbstractCommand.java:527)
 at com.sencha.cli.AbstractCommand.configure(AbstractCommand.java:114)
 at com.sencha.command.Sencha.main(Sencha.java:128)
 Caused by: Not a framework directory : /home/tanmay/amit_mob/sdk/tools
 at com.sencha.command.Sencha.setSdkPath(Sencha.java:361)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
 at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
 at com.sencha.cli.AbstractCommand$Property.set(AbstractCommand.java:394)
 at com.sencha.cli.AbstractCommand.processConfigParam(AbstractCommand.java:527)
 at com.sencha.cli.AbstractCommand.configure(AbstractCommand.java:114)
 at com.sencha.command.Sencha.main(Sencha.java:128)
```

Please help me.

Answer (score 1):

I forget to download sencha touch.If you face this problem then download sencha touch from http://www.sencha.com/products/touch/download/

and extract in any folder.

```
  tanmay@tanmay-desk:~/amit_mob$ sencha -sdk /home/tanmay/mobile_app/touch-2.4.2 generate app MyApp /home/tanmay/amit_mob
```

and run above command.Change your directory please...

Answer (score 0):

Hi follow the [documentation](https://docs.sencha.com/touch/2.4/getting_started/getting_started.html)

Command prompt / Terminal enter the below comments:

```
$ sencha -sdk /Users/dev2/Documents/Source/Sencha/touch-2.4.2 generate app MySampleApp /Users/dev2/Documents/Source/Sencha\ -\ Apps
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Not specifically for the scenario AGM had, Just in case for somebody else has this issue:

Check the 2 paths, sdk and app directroy, if they have spaces double quote the path like this:

Sencha -sdk "C:\Program Files\Sencha\Cmd\6.5.3.6" xxxxxxxxxx